# Connection between pairs and list in scheme

Tags: list, scheme, cons

I am trying to understand the connection between pairs and lists in scheme. Let's take a look at the following scheme expression:

```
(((a) (b)) ((c) (d)))
```

I wish to count the number of pairs in the above expression, so I constructed it in the following manner:

```
(list (list (list 'a) (list 'b)) (list (list 'c) (list 'd)))
 => (((a) (b)) ((c) (d)))

(list 'a),(list 'b),(list 'c),(list 'd) - 4 pairs
(list (list 'a) (list 'b)) and (list (list 'c) (list 'd)) - 2 pairs
(list (list (list 'a) (list 'b)) (list (list 'c) (list 'd))) - 1 pair
```

So far, 7 pairs. Supposed to be 10.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple fact: a proper list with `n` elements has `n` pairs:

[image]

So, which is the total number of elements in your list?

Lists like `(a)` have one element, so they have one pair. You have four of them, so you have 4 pairs.

Lists like `(thing1 thing2`) have two elements, so they have two pairs. You have three of them (the two internals containing the lists like `(a)`, and one external), so you have 3 x 2 = 6 other pairs.

In total, you have 6 + 4 = 10 pairs.